# How does one achieve the coupling of an html-element (representing a specific data-item) to its related data-item at the element's click handling?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, event-handling, event-delegation

We are displaying JOSN in a for each loop and adding the data to some html.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://***************************',
  success: function (data) {
    var html = '<div class="row">';
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, value) {
      html += '<button onclick="storeVar(this);" value="' + value.ItemCode + '" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" class="btn btn-outline-fleet"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-right-from-square pe-1"></i>Check Stock</button></div>';
    });
    html += '</div>';
    $('#output').html(html);
  }
});
```

Each button is storing the value what is referred to as ItemCode.

JSON DATA

```
 "[
    {\"ItemCode\":\"123abc\",\"Description\":\"example1\"},
    {\"ItemCode\":\"abc123\",\"Description\":\"example2\"}
    ]"
```

JS

```
function storeVar(el) {
  var ffref = el.getAttribute('value'); 
  **var selected-description = GET THE DESCRIPTION FOR THE ITEM-CODE OF THE CLICKED BUTTON VALUE AND STORE IT AS A VARIABLE**
}
```

When the button is clicked it stores the value (what is the ItemCode) to the variable ffref.

**We want to get the Description that is equal to the ItemCode but cannot figure out how to do this**

**Attempt**:

```
function storeVar(el) {
  var ffref = el.getAttribute('value');

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://********************',
    success: function (data) {
      var json = [];
      var resObj = JSON.parse(data);
      for (var key in resObj) {
        if (resObj[key].ItemCode == ffref) {
          json.push(resObj[key]);
        }
      }
      alert(json);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Store the JSON array in a variable that `storeVar` can also access, then search the appropriate data within it given the item code. Perhaps even reformat the array to a `{key: value}` object so you can access the data more directly.

Comment: By the way it's very bad practice to construct javascript code (the `onclick` code) as a string. Better create the button using `let btn = document.createElement("button")` and then use `addEventListener()` to make it interactive.

Comment: Please see update, still having issues maybe I am being stupid?

Comment: Tangential: because of how the code is written it's hard to think about what's happening. It **looks** like you're also adding closing `</div>` tags on every loop iteration, which will generate incorrect DOM. I'd argue for spending some time checking out current JS practices--it'll help a lot.

Comment: @richag ... Regarding the so far provided answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom attribute in your `buttons` and set it to the `Description` value like this

```js
var data = [
    {"ItemCode":"123abc","Description":"example1"},
    {"ItemCode":"abc123","Description":"example2"}
];

var html = '<div class="row">';
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    html += '<button onclick="storeVar(this);" value="' + value.ItemCode + '" type="button" data-description="'+value.Description+'" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" class="btn btn-outline-fleet"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-right-from-square pe-1"></i>Check Stock</button>';
});
html += '</div>';
$('#output').html(html);

function storeVar(el){
  var ffref = el.getAttribute('value');
  var description = el.getAttribute('data-description');
  console.log(description);
}
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I used the custom `data-description` attribute to set it to the `Description` value.
For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest an implementation which somehow separates the created markup from the event- and the data-handling.

As for the OP's problem, I would use a helper function which generates the markup of a single button. There I would utilize a custom [`data-*` global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) which for the provided data could be named e.g. `data-item-id` and would get/have assigned the value of an item-data's `ItemCode` property.

The parsed json-value is a list of such items. And since each item features its unique `ItemCode` identifier-key, I suggest the creation of an `ItemCode`-key based [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance as lookup-table. The advantage is the direct relationship of an item's stored data and its id which is part of any button's custom data-attribute. In case the entries of a data-item are going to be increased or their naming has been changed, one does not need to reflect these changes as additional data-properties of an item's related button. The id is always enough.

And the event-handling should be based on [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Thus, one does subscribe just a single handler to all of the buttons' common parent-node. This handler ensures for each click that the event-target is always a button element. Since it in addition of knowing the currently clicked button element also lays within the scope of the data-lookup, it can easily pass the item related id and the lookup-reference with a forwarding call to the OP's data-storage handler-function.

```js
// the json value retrieved from th API call.
const jsonValue =
  '[{"ItemCode":"123abc","Description":"example1","additionalKey":"additional value"},{"ItemCode":"abc123","Description":"example2","otherKey":"other value"}]';

createAndEnableItemButtons($('#output'), jsonValue);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%!important; bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function handleDataStorage(itemId, lookup) {
  const { Description: description } = lookup.get(itemId);

  console.log({ description });
}

function createButtonMarkup({ ItemCode }) {
  return `
    <button type="button" data-item-id="${ ItemCode }" class="btn btn-outline-fleet">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-up-right-from-square pe-1"></i>
      Check Stock
    </button>`;
}

function createAndEnableItemButtons($root, jsonValue) {
  // data handling.

  const dataList = JSON.parse(jsonValue);

  // create an `ItemCode` based map for fast lookups.
  const dataLookup = new Map(
    dataList.map(({ ItemCode, ...restData }) => [ItemCode, restData])
  );

  // just in order to show how a key-based lookup-table could look like.
  console.log({
    dataById: Object.fromEntries([...dataLookup.entries()]),
    dataList,
  });

  // event-delegation based event-handling and markup creation.

  const $parent = $('<div class="row"/>');

  // - event delegation ... part 1 ... a single handler at the parent node.
  $parent[0].addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  
    // - event delegation ... part 2 ... always ensure an HTMLButton element.
    if (target = target.closest('button')) {

      // - forwarding to the data storage handler.
      handleDataStorage(target.dataset.itemId, dataLookup);
    }
  });

  $parent.html(
    dataList
      .reduce((markup, data) => {

        return markup + createButtonMarkup(data);

      }, '')
  );
  $root.append($parent);
}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```